# A LINQ extension that I wrote will not work with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have an extension method defined like so:

```
public static TSource MaxBy<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> collection, Func<TSource, TResult> func) where TSource : class
{
    var comparer = Comparer<TSource>.Default;
    TSource maxItem = null;
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        if (comparer.Compare(item, maxItem) > 0)
            maxItem = item;
    }
    return maxItem;
}
```

which I then use in the following LINQ-to-Entities query:

```
var balancesQuery = from t in db.Transactions
                    where t.UserId == userId
                    group t by t.CurrencyCode into tg
                    let tMaxDate = tg.MaxBy(i => i.TsCreate)
                    join c in db.Currencies on tg.Key equals c.CurrencyCode
                    select new { Currency = c, Balance = tMaxDate.Balance }
```

So what I'm doing is - get the newest transaction (MaxBy TsCreate) in each currency (group by CurrencyCode) and then select the balance against each of those transactions.

My problem is - this **does not work** with Entity Framework (LINQ-to-Entities; I get:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Transaction MaxBy[Transaction,DateTime](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'[Transaction], System.Func'2[Transaction,System.DateTime])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

The same query works with LINQ to SQL.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to make it work with Entity Framework?
2. Or maybe there is a better way of querying for the same information, which would work with Entity Framework?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't the query same as:

```
var balancesQuery = from t in db.Transactions
                    where t.UserId == userId
                    group t by t.CurrencyCode into tg
                    join c in db.Currencies on tg.Key equals c.CurrencyCode
                    select new { 
                        Currency = c, 
                        Balance = tg.OrderByDescending(i => i.TsCreate).Take(1).Balance 
                    };
```

Comment: Indeed, this is what I was looking for... Thanks! I'm just wondering - would it be possible to write the LINQ-to-Entities query so that it would generate a SQL query with GROUP BY CurrencyCode HAVING MAX(TsCreate)? Because the subselect query is ok, but not really efficient (for a small number of currencies it doesn't matter of course)

Comment: I think in linq it would still lead to sub query because there is not `having` - having is perhaps created if you co `where` on grouped data.

Comment: The `Take(1)` needs to be a `FirstOrDefault`, I think? As `Take` returns a sequence rather than an element.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use extensions with LINQ queries that actually pull data from the database as it's impossible for this to be turned into SQL. However, you can do this by returning the results into memory using `ToArray()` or `ToList()` to trigger the database query executing and then call your extension functions on resultant real data in memory.